# How can I pass an argument to one implementor of an Interface but not the others (without passing it in the constructor)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

The application I'm working on consists of Profiles and Steps. Each Profile consists of a number of steps and there are 4 kinds of steps:

- **Sequential** : After this step completes, go to next step in sequence.
- **Jump** : After this step completes, go to step with ID.
- **Evaluated** : After this step completes, the next step ID is determined based on the results of a certain method.
- **Terminal** : This step is the last step.

My `Step` interface has an abstract method called `public abstract Step getNextStep()`. Each step type implements this method as required.

The problem is that the EvaluatedStep requires a single parameter, let's call it `Parameter p`, and none of the other step types require any parameter.

I tacked this by changing the method header in the interface to `public abstract Step getNextStep(Parameter p);` but I know this is not a good solution. **What would be a better way of doing this?**

NOTE:

- I can not pass `Parameter p` to the EvaluationStep constructor because the parameter is only available at the time when `getNextStep()` needs to be called.
- `Parameter p` might be a conglomeration of different parameters in the future so the solution to this problem has to be flexible. In other words, right now I only need to pass `Parameter p` to `getNextStep()` but in future I might need to pass a bunch of different parameters `getNextStep(Parameter p,Argument a,Something s)`. **How can I avoid this**?

Comment: interfaces don't have the "abstract" keyword. do you mean abstract class, or interface?

Comment: Yes they do, you just don't have to write it out explicitly.

Comment: I'm confused about how you'd **call** `getNextStep()`. If you have a `Step` object (i.e., you don't know what type it is), you must either pass a parameter or not pass a parameter — how do you know which to do? If you **know** you have an `EvaluatedStep`, cast to `EvaluatedStep` and you can call whatever EvaluatedStep-specific function you want (including an overloaded version of `getNextStep()` if you want).

Comment: It's something like
`Parameter p = getParameter;` `Step nextStep = currentStep.getNextStep(p)`. The getNextStep() implementation chooses whether or not to use the Parameter or not.

Comment: why not have the interface have 2 methods which overload each-other: 1 with a parameter, and one without. Also, to overcome the flexebility issue, you could use a custom object as the parameter and simply add getters & setters to it as you like, or you could use solutions like using a hash table as a parameter.

Comment: I thought of the 2-overloaded-methods idea but I would like to get the next step through a single call and not have to check which instance of step I'm working with. That hash table idea is brilliant, thought! Hadn't occurred to me at all :)

Comment: When the steps are created isn't it possible to inject the Parameter ? For eg: When you create an object of Evaluated step , Evaluate obj = new Evaluated(parameter) where parameter is an object of type Parameter. With this Evaluated step will have a member variable of type Parameter and will use this parameter inside the getNextStep method implementation since it knows it needs to use the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use varargs on the signature, like this:

```
pubic abstract Step getNextStep(Object... parameters)
```

Then it could be called in any of these ways:

```
seq.getNextStep();
eval.getNextStep(p);
future.getNextStep(p,a,s);
```

And all would match the interface. Inside the implementations, you reference them as array members, if you need them:

```
public Step getNextStep(Object... parameters){
    if ( parameters.length > 0 && parameters[0] instanceof Parameter ){
        Parameter p = (Parameter) parameters[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to define some `StepParameter` interface that `Parameter`, `Argument`, and `Something` will all extend. Then you can declare it as taking `StepParameter...` instead of `Object...`. Otherwise, you could call it with anything, like `String`, `Integer`, `Rectangle` ... all kinds of objects that it wouldn't have any idea what to do with.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the parameter consumers to the abstract class:

```
abstract class Step {

    public abstract Step getNextStep();

    public void addParameter(Parameter p) {
    }

    public void addParameter(Argument a) {
    }

    public void addParameter(Something s) {
    }
}

class Evaluated extends Step {

    Parameter p;

    @Override
    public Step getNextStep() {

    }

    @Override
    public void addParameter(Parameter p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's pretty smart. How's this for an improvement: we declare a new empty interface called `NextStepResolutionParameter` which is implemented by `Parameter`,`Argument` and `Something`, then we need only one extra method in the `Step` interface: `addNextStepResolutionParameter(NextStepResolutionParameter p)`?

Comment: @W.K.S - That would work as a refinement - I only added the three methods because you had the three types in your question. Making them all implement an interface would certainly improve your code.